# springboot error on the application compile

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a problem with springboot after creating my springboot project. I filled out my application.properties to have access to the database. And then I tried to compile by maven and I encountered these errors. I was unsuccessful.

```html
##DataSource settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/BD_GESTION_OPERATION?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&userSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasoutce.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

##Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

##Disabling spring basic security
security.basic.enabled=false

##Start up port
server.port=8082

##Specify DBMS
spring.jpa.database=ORACLE

##Show/Hide SQL queries
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

##Hibernate DDL Auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

##Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

##Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect
```

```html
The errors are as follows:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Could you provide your pom.xml

Comment: You lack only your Oracle Driver as a dependency in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you forgot to provide the dependency in maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>d:/projects/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Note that to get that working you need to download the jar file. here is a quick explanation https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

**Note** Im asumming you are missing that but i did not look at your pom file